# Redirect the not logged in users to login page

Tags: php

I tried many many times... But it does not redirect to anywhere:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        header("Location: LogIn.php");
        exit;
    }
    else{
        //Content of the webpage
    }
?>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, maybe `$_SESSION['username'])` is set?

Comment: **urgent** <- This here kills your question and why you want to render entire page under `else` condition?

Comment: Try  if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) && !empty($_SESSION['username']) ) {

Comment: 1. as @Pekka웃 wrote. 2. Maybe LogIn.php doesn't exists? Try echo something there to see if there is good if condition or print `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: Mind case sensitivity for filenames if you're on Unix (likely, if on shared hosting) Wait a sec. Always mind case sensitivity regardless when working with PHP IMO.

Comment: Don't use "empty" as per cartina's comment. This will go horribly wrong if you allow usernames to be just "0" (i.e. $username = "0";)

Comment: Also the `else` statement makes no sense here, only adds indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and it works for me. Be sure not to have any output before the `header` function. It can also be caused by `error_reporting`. Try using `error_reporting(0);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute URl like this:

```
<?php  
    session_start();  
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {  
        header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/LogIn.php");  
        exit;  
    }  
    else{  
        //Content of the webpage  
    }  
?>
```

Another thing to try is make sure no headers are being sent first; there will be a visible error if any are on the page.

Comment: Only absolute urls? You got to be joking

Comment: It is possible to use `header("location:LogIn.php");` aswell.

Comment: I've corrected that, sorry, although i'm sure i read that somewhere.

Comment: According to [RFC 2616 14.30 Location](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30), an absolute URI must be specified in the Location header field.

Comment: @Oswald The HTTP protocol spec doesn't apply to PHP.

Comment: An absolute URL is __required__ per definition, and while it might “work” in certain clients, there are always some that refuse to handle this correctly. So instead of saying “it works” one should do it the _correct_ way in the first place, everything else is just stupid.

Comment: @DannyBeckett True. But the HTTP RFC applies to the output that PHP generates, if that output is to be interpreted as a HTTP message.

Comment: @Oswald I take it back: `HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself` - from the [PHP manual](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

Answer (score 0):

First check whether `session` variable has the value and entered into `if` condition.If that will works try with full url in header.